# Extending/Inheriting enums in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have an enum:

```
CREATE TYPE title AS ENUM ('Mr','Mrs', ...etc);
```

I would like to create a second enum, or extend the existing enum, such that it contains the same data, but with additional options that are only permissible to certain classes (in a polymorphism-style fashion). Essentially:

```
('Mr', 'Mrs', 'Dr')
```

Would work for a certain class `Professional` derived from `Person`, whereas `Layman` (also derived from `Person`) still only has access to the original minimal set. `title` is an attribute of `Person`

I am new to object-relational databases, what is the most clean way to do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this as an actual enum in PostgreSQL.

This would be better suited to a look-up table, where you can have an extra column for conditions. A title list is a poor use for an enum anyway, since it's inevitable you'll be regularly adding new titles, and the set is large.

Honestly, for PostgreSQL discard the "object-" part. Focus on the "relational".